# Pop to first ViewController in Navigation stack

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

In my navigation stack, I have 2 viewcontrollers, which were pushed to the navigation stack. Over that I have a PresentModalViewController as rootviewcontroller and I push 2 more viewcontrollers over it. So the navigation stack will be like

> ViewController
>
> ViewController
>
> PresentModalViewController as rootviewcontroller
>
> ViewController
>
> ViewController

From the topmost viewcontroller, on a button click, I would like to move to the bottommost viewcontroller. The viewcontrollers in between should be popped or dismissed. How is it possible. 
I have tried `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` and `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` without any success.

Comment: Means you want to Jump 5th controller to first controller right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used delegates to solve this problem.

```
Class A.h
@protocol MyDelegateClass
- (void)didLoadHomeView; 


Class B.h
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<MyHomeViewDelegate>

Class B.m
- (void)didLoadHomeView
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

Class C.h
@interface MyCurrentViewController : UIViewController
{
    id <MyLoadHomeDelegate> homeDelegate; 
}
    @property (nonatomic,assign) id <MyLoadHomeDelegate>   homeDelegate;

Class C.m
-(IBAction) OnHome:(id)sender{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    if (self.homeDelegate) {
        [homeDelegate didLoadHomeView];
    }
```

}

The `ModalViewController`, which is the current `RootViewController` is dismissed in the `OnHome:(id)sender` method in `MyCurrentVIewController` class. After dismissing the `ModalViewController`, I popped to the current rootviewcontroller in the navigation stack, which is the home view(firstViewController). The above code works perfectly in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this this will work

```
            NSArray *vcs = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:[vcs objectAtIndex:[vcs count]-2] animated:YES];
```

Comment: When I log the navigation array, I only see 3 viewcontrollers as I have set the presentmodalviewcontroller(viewController3) as my rootviewcontroller.

Comment: you need to change [vcs count]-2 or 3 or 4 whatever you want.

Comment: If the navigation array has only 3 elements, how is it possible to pop to the 4th viewcontroller

Comment: yen that also i m say you need to set value according to your requirement.

Comment: I think you are not understanding my question. My presentmodalviewcontroller is set as rootviewcontroller, because of which the first 2 viewcontrollers at the bottom of the stack are missing from the navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` using the `navigationController` of your `ModalViewController` .  Then you should use `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`. Then again you should do `popToRootViewControllerAnimated`.